# Minifying Or/And expressions in Java?

Tags: java

I've always been curious if it's possible to simplify an Or expression Java. Example:

```
int mapVal = occurrenceMap.get(node.nextNode.nodeVal);

if (mapVal != null || mapVal != 5 )
```

versus...

```
if (occurrenceMap.get(node.nextNode.nodeVal) != ( null || 1) )
```

IMO, the second is more readable, but wondering if the language supports something like this.

Comment: I'd shorten it by not making `get` calls twice.

Comment: Assign once, evaluate twice.

Comment: The second expression has two meanings. the `get` value will be checked against the return of the value, or against both values? Because the boolean expression `X || Y` will return a boolean value.

Comment: Please don't change the context of your question!

Comment: Java do not support operator overloading. What you actually want is possible in Kotlin with `in` operator, and it can be overloaded for any type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `if (occurrenceMap.get(node.nextNode.nodeVal) != ( null || 1) )`
>
> the second is more readable, but wondering if the language supports
>   something like this.

No Java not support that.

For a good solution I would like to use :

```
Integer i = occurrenceMap.get(node.nextNode.nodeVal);
if (i != null || i != 1)
```

---

**Note :** as [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877911/minifying-or-and-expressions-in-java#comment88758152_50878019) mention in comment primitive int or type in general can't be null in Java.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen correct The OP changed his question from the first version I thought it is an Integer

Answer (score 6):

Use [getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)

```
occurrenceMap.getOrDefault(node.nextNode.nodeVal, 5) != 5
```

Comment: Your vision side is really different and really nice you deserve +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're into simplifying boolean expressions you should learn about some axioms and laws:

- !!a = a
- (!a || a) = true
- (!a && a) = false
- (true && a) = a
- (false && a) = false
- (true || a) = true
- (false || a) = a
- (!a || !b) = !(a && b)
- (!a && !b) = !(a || b)
- (a != b) = !(a == b)
- (a <= b) = (b > a)
- (a >= b) = (b < a)

The second one you've mentioned can't possibly be used in
Java because `(a || b)` already has a meaning so `a == (c || d)` already has a fixed meaning and changing this would probably break a lot of code. There *might* be languages that support such notations but they'll use a different operator instead of the binary boolean operator because otherwise it'd be impossible to distinguish what the programmer actually wants.

You could absolutely add such a feature to Java but you'd have to create a new operator to do this. But as of now: Java doesn't have this, and most languages don't.

Some languages allow you to do things like "a < b < c" which not all languages support (you'll have to write "a < b AND b < c").

You technically can create helper functions for this such as
"if isOneOf(mapVal, a, b)" but probably this is not going to be used widespread (most importantly because it'd require some runtime trickery to do this).

Comment: OP says "Something like this". He knows he can't write it like that in Java. He's wondering if there's a syntax to "factor" the condition

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. It was too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

First, `int` cannot be `null`. You don't need to check against `null` if you have an `int`. It just *cannot* happen.

Here is a method that checks whether a value is equal to any of a list of values:

```
public static <T> boolean anyEquals(T value, T... values) {
    for (T val: values) {
        if (val == value) { // or val.equals(value)
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;

    // implementation with streams
    // return Arrays.stream(values).anyMatch(x -> x == value); // or x.equals(value)
}
```

Usage (supposing you are using `Integer`s instead of `int`):

```
Integer i = ...;
boolean b = anyEquals(i, 5, 10, 15);
```